# Computing average on a list of values for each value

Tags: shell, awk

I have a huge file (50k lines) with the following format:

```
52370581 2116
17996781 4314
47818829 2584
61421045 2158
...
25145813 2274
```

The first value can be present multiple times and I want to compute the average of the 2nd value for each 1st value, using the terminal. Ideally, I'd want the median, the min and max too. I can to it on all the values quite easily with `awk` but I was wondering how to get that done for each value.

Comment: Do you want the median **or** the average? It's not the same thing.

Comment: @Nifle he said he wants the median as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{c[$1]++;s[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in c)print i,(s[i]/c[i])}' test.in
```

More readably:

```
awk '
{ # Every line
    # Increment the key, add value to its sum
    count[$1]++
    sum[$1] += $2
}
END {
    # Go through all the numbers we saw
    for(number in count) {
        # Print the number followed by the average (sum/count) of its values
        print number, (sum[number]/count[number])
    }
}
' test.in
```

Note that the numbers will be output in a more-or-less random order (some hash of the keys). Getting min and max isn't so bad, just add them after `count` and `sum` in the first block. Median requires tracking every number. You can do it with a 2d array (or awk's emulation thereof), but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could double vote just for the explanation which have allowed me to understand and go further!

Answer (score 0):

For avarage

`awk '{if(NR==1){i=$1;}} {if($1~i){j+=$2;k++}} END{print "Average is " (j/k)}' <filename>`

this will provide you in case you want to do it only for the value in first line. Instead of `NR==0`, if you pass a variable, you can do it for any line specific case. Now if you want to do it for each line, then below awk will do it in one pass

`awk '{value[$1]+=$2;count[$1]++} END{for(indx in value)print "Avarage of " indx " is " (value[indx]/count[indx])}' <filename>`

awk has two dimensional array, but i'm not familiar with that, so using 2 arrays to keep sum of the elements and count. Any other operation, we need to change the script based on the operation

Comment: `awk` lines start at 1, so `NR == 0` is always false.

Comment: oops Sorry my mistake, I should have tested once before posting :) Thanks @Kevin